# AAD Graph client: Creating AD group with length greater than 120 chars

Tags: c#, azure-ad-graph-api

When I call _activeDirectoryClient.Groups.AddGroupAsync(group) where group's displayname is larger than 120 char, it throws the following exception:

> Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataErrorException: Unsupported or invalid query
>   filter clause specified for property 'displayName' of resource
>   'Group'. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException:
>   An error occurred while processing this request. --->
>   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException:
>   {"odata.error":{"code":"Request_UnsupportedQuery","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Unsupported
>   or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'displayName' of
>   resource 'Group'."}}} at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object
>   source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object
>   source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)

PS: I asked this in [Microsoft Graph github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/159). But, I was told to post it here instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that error is not caused by AddGroupAsync function , if group's displayname exceeds its' allowed length , it will throw below error :

```
Invalid value specified for property 'displayName' of resource 'Group'.
```

Your error seems invalid query filter on displayname property , after testing , when using query filter on displayname property(greater than 120 chars length) :

```
https://graph.windows.net/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/groups?$filter=displayName eq 'xxxxxxx'&api-version=1.6
```

It shows same error as yours , that seems server side restricts the length of filter on properties. If you want azure ad graph api supports that , you could send a feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory?query=revoke) .